# Remove RSS feed image

Tags: php, joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)
>   [DOM Remove Child from RSS XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198245/dom-remove-child-from-rss-xml)

I am using fetch rss right now to display 1 new article from an RSS feed on my homepage. I would like to reduce the size of my homepage, but unfortunately the feed often posts large images which slow it down. Is there a way to modify one of the existing RSS feed modules (or fetchrss) or write a new one that will remove images from the feed before posting?
Thanks

Comment: and since RSS is just XML basically any of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+element+dom+php

Comment: you can solve this also by preventing the <img> tags from being inserted in the DOM... that means server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all  tag NOT to display by adding CSS class:

```
#rss_container img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this way the images will still get loaded by the browser... it is better to strip out the img tags in a callback function.